# Which thing should be learn first by a beginner Javascript or DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scripting

I know the basics of html ans css, and now I want to make my self a good front end developer, so I decided to learn JavaScript, and I got this book.

[DOM Scripting: Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model: Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004I6DD88)

I started to learn about JavaScript then i read that JavaScript is totally based on DOM scripting, and now I am confused what I should learn first. Should I learn JavaScript basics, or DOM scripting first?

I'm a beginner for both JavaScript and DOM Scripting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn Javascript. The DOM is merely an API that is provided by the browser. Once you know how JS works, you will be better equipped to handle the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

DOM Scripting is just a generic term for any scripting language that manipulates the DOM.  If you're going to use JavaScript as a front end developer on the web, then you HAVE to understand the DOM.

I guess my point is that JavaScript and DOM Scripting aren't necessarily two different concepts (Edit: this statement mostly applies to the concept of using JavaScript in a meaningful way on a web page).  Your question is effectively the same thing as asking "Which should I learn first, Java or Object Oriented Programming?"

Comment: Well, they are and they aren't.  You can absolutely write javascript without touching the DOM.  You just won't be able to affect anything on the page.

Comment: @Davy8 True.  I guess I specialized the answer to his particular context.

Comment: Adding this JS won't affect the page?  `i=10;for(;;){i*=i}` :)

Comment: @mrk It would, but when I say "meaningful" I meant that it would do something productive and it would enable a positive user experience.  That's just mean.  This is turning in to a semantics discussion now :-P

Answer (score 1):

First, learn a little about Javascript, because you can learn about the DOM, but to play with it or alter the DOM you need to code in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

DOM is an API that lets you interact with HTML or XML with scripting languages - mainly Javascript. Probably you want to learn Javascript syntax and basic programming architecture and naturally you will be led to DOM manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

The DOM is an interface provided by the browser based on the elements of the document that it is executing.

In most of the books and courses, there is an overlap because the DOM is the natural interaction point of many JS operations. So, studying the DOM per se might be less effective than the studying how JS + DOM work. But you can definitely study the DOM to understand its treatments of elements.